# why bind arguments are not pointed to actual function parameters

Tags: javascript

why limit is 20 rather than el=20 because in isFullAge.bind(this,20) in which 20 is the last argument ,so it has to pass to 'el' parameter,but why it is set to 'limit' parameter?

```
var years = [1990, 1965, 1937, 2005, 1998];

    function arrayCalc(arr, fn) {
        var arrRes = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arrRes.push(fn(arr[i]));
        }
        return arrRes;
    }

    function calculateAge(le) {
        return 2016 - le;
    }

    function isFullAge(limit,el)  
     {
        return el >= limit;
    }

    var ages = arrayCalc(years, calculateAge);
    var fullJapan = arrayCalc(ages, isFullAge.bind(this, 20)); // i'm confused here
    console.log(ages);
    console.log(fullJapan);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *first* argument becomes the `this` value. Each subsequent value is mapped onto the arguments **in order**, left to right. They are not assigned from the end backwards.

`20` is the *first* argument after the `this` value in the call to `bind` so it is assigned to `limit` because `limit` is the *first* argument.

Had you said:

```
isFullAge.bind(this, 20, example))
```

… then `example` would be assigned to `el` because `el` is the second argument and `example` would be the second argument after the `this` value.

Comment: But 'el' is already set to the arugements from the 'function arrayCalc(arr, fn)' it should be the first argument right?

Comment: @sAGarm — See how I start the second half of the answer with "Had you said". It's a hypothetical.